# How to enable Calico network policy on the existing AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I want to enable Calico network policy on existing AKS cluster. Is there any way to do that?

I found the following statement on the official Microsoft documentation that, **"You can't enable network policy on an existing AKS cluster. To use Azure Network Policy, you must use the Azure CNI plug-in and define your own virtual network and subnets."**

But I raising this question because what if we need to implement this on the existing production level clusters??

If there is no option then for only this thing we need to do various time consuming operations on that production servers and then we have to enable policy.

Please help me on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't enable the network policy on the existing AKS cluster. It shows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-network-policies#create-an-aks-cluster-and-enable-network-policy):

> The network policy feature can only be enabled when the cluster is
> created. You can't enable network policy on an existing AKS cluster.

Comment: Yes I know, But what if we have to implement this with production level clusters? should we remove entire cluster and create new cluster for only this??

Comment: @Kaivalya Maybe it's the only way, but you can store the useful data first.

Comment: For the record, it *is* possible to install the tigera-operator even on top of Azure CNI and thus have rules from GlobalNetworkPolicy objects applied at cluster level, instead of namespace level. It is unfortunately poorly documented in the Calico project repo, but possible. Source: did this in our production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes right now there is no option to add network policy on existing AKS cluster, We have to recreate entire cluster environment. I am in same situation like I need to do it in multiple environments

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Pavan. This is a useful response, but effectively reiterates Charles' answer from last month. Please be sure to review existing answers before contributing a new one. In the future, once you have a bit more reputation, you'll be able to upvote answers you find useful.